# In VBA, is it always better to use With, End With?

Tags: excel, vba

For even two lines of code referencing the same object, is it always faster to write extra lines to incorporate With and End With?

For example:

```
If Target.Column <> 1 Or Target.Row >= 100 Then Exit Sub
```

Versus:

```
With Target
    If .Column <> 1 Or .Row >= 100 Then Exit Sub
End With
```

Is this overkill?

Is it dependent on the code itself to weigh up referencing an object twice vs. writing three separate lines? Or always faster to write three lines?

On the subject of speed - what is the optimal way to write this line in terms of processing speed? i.e. is the second test more quickly read as

```
> 99
```

than

```
>= 100
```

?

Does it matter which order I test the row number and column number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tested the speed of using `With` vs. referencing the `Range` object at every instance using the following subs:

```
Sub WithSpeed()
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
Dim av As Double
Dim Target As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long

'Remember time when macro starts
StartTime = Timer

Set Target = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)

For j = 1 To 5
    For i = 1 To 1000000
        With Target
            If .Column <> 1 Or .Row >= 100 Then Exit For
        End With
    Next i
    av = av + Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
Next j

'Determine how many seconds code took to run
Debug.Print 1, av / 5
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub NoWithSpeed()
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
Dim av As Double
Dim Target As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long

'Remember time when macro starts
StartTime = Timer

Set Target = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)

For j = 1 To 5
    For i = 1 To 1000000
         If Target.Column <> 1 Or Target.Row >= 100 Then Exit For
    Next i
    av = av + Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
Next j

'Determine how many seconds code took to run
Debug.Print 2, av / 5
End Sub
```

The results:

```
first sub:  
> 1             2.966   
> 1             3.04   
> 1             2.726   
> 1             2.634  
> 1             2.616
second sub:
> 2             2.924 
> 2             2.708 
> 2             2.506 
> 2             2.496 
> 2             2.724
```

Each sub loops 5 million times. I ran each sub 5 times totalling at 25 million loops for each sub. After the 5 million loops, the sub prints out the average time a million loops took.

**Averages:**
1: 2.80 seconds
2: 2.67 seconds

I firmly believe this difference is negligible and can be attributed to flukes in the PC's processing speeds.
When you start referencing in more lines it *may* matter, but it is unlikely that using `With` will have a lot of impact on your code's speed.

Still I highly advise using it, to improve code readability and to prevent typing errors.

Comment: Couldn't ask for a more comprehensive test than that...! Your insight is very much appreciated. Many thanks, Tim.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: `When you start referencing in more lines it may matter, but it is unlikely that using With will have a lot of impact on your code's speed.` Yup and that is where you will start seeing the difference :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, of course more lines can be faster, a lot. In that case You won't see and feel any difference, but at least You will build a habit to always start like this.

I'm not sure about that >99 and =>100 case, but I think in =>100 option code is working on 2 conditions - more time spent.

In VBA there is no matter which condition is first in your situation. VBA is checking both conditions, even if the first one is true. The difference would give code like:

```
With Target
    If .Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If .Row >= 100 then exit sub
End With
```

In that situation the order have impact, always put more likely case as first.

Comment: Thanks very much. So is it safe to assume that if I am referencing an object on two occasions or more, then it is faster to use With and End With? Your second point also makes sense - I didn't realise that both statements would be checked if the first is already met.

Comment: Yes, correct.
I was also surprised, but unfortunately it is the way VBA works, found it there: http://www.shamrock-software.eu/vb.htm - really good lecture.